# Can I clean stucco smears off aluminum with muriatic acid?

Tags: cleaning, metal

I have an aluminum wall cap for a range hood fan that has some stucco smears on it from doing masonry work in the vicinity. I tried mechanically scraping but it doesn't go. I was wondering if I used muriatic acid (1:10 water solution), I am sure it will work but will it damage the aluminum. I have used acid a lot before but only bricks, never metal.

Will doing this damage the aluminum?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3):

Muriatic acid attacks aluminum with great vigor, giving off hydrogen gas and heat.

The oxide layer that is found on all aluminum would initially delay the reaction, but after a few seconds to a few minutes, depending on the thickness of the layer, the reaction would proceed.

It will turn the aluminum black and give it a rough surface, then eventually the acid will eat completely through the aluminum, leaving empty space where the wall cap used to be if allowed to continue.

No acid of any kind should ever be used on aluminum for cleaning purposes.

Comment: hmm, I just did it and it turned out fine. neutralized it with baking soda

Comment: @amphibient Must have had a good thick coating of oxide -- anodized perhaps -- and you neutralized before the acid got through the oxide. For an entertaining demo, drop a small ball of aluminum foil into the acid in a cup and watch it disappear in a short time.

Comment: I wonder if white vinegar (5% acetic acid) would have been a better choice for removal, but what the OP did seems to have worked. Muriatic acid (hydrochloric acid) is used to remove mortar from bricks, Vinegar is often used to descale tea kettles and tankless water heaters, but removing mortar might require hydrochloric acid.

Answer (score 1):

Muraitic acid will attack aluminium

Citric acid will not attack aluminium and should be effective (albeit less effective than muriatic acid) against the lime in the smears.